# Which edition of Midrash Tanchuma is this?

Tags: midrash, publications

There are a couple editions of Midrash Tanchuma floating around.

The following is based on the Buber edition from Vilna:

http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/tohen.asp?id=280

But, can anyone discern what edition the following is based on?

http://www.tsel.org/torah/tanhuma/index.html

Thanks.

Comment: Broken link. I know the OP’s deleted his account, but does anyone have a cache of the original?